# “Decrease” the measure in OLAP Cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, with-statement, measures

I have an OLAP Cube in which  there is a Parent-Child Account Dimension.
My goal is to set a certain measure value on the GROSS-PROFIT Account , with a certain logic : 
GROSS PROFIT = REVENUES - COSTS

GROSS PROFIT is the parent of REVENUES and COSTS in my account hierarchy, and now the measure shows me the sum (obviously) , not the substraction.

The measure is named [Measures].[Report] 
I don’t know how to return, in my measure, the substraction only for the GROSS PROFIT Account , so please help me.

Tks a lot

Daniel

Comment: We really need to see the MDX that you have tried so far, even if it errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem , I saw that exists an “operator column” in the dimension definition, that permits to perform some operation like substraction and addition between members only specifying a certain value column (setted for ex to “+” or “-“)